# Pytest how to conduct testing for function returning dataframe that needs snowflake connection?

Tags: python, pandas, pytest, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Say if we have an object as below and I would like to do a unit test (pytest) on the `extract_data_from_db` method particularly **without connecting to the actual database**, is that possible?

```
import pandas as pd
import snowflake.connector

class Something:
   def __init__(self):
      self.database = snowflake.connector.connect(
        user='test_user',
        account='test_account',
        password='test_pwd',
    )
   
   @property
   def extract_data_from_db(self):
      query = 'select * from table'
      data = pd.read_sql_query(query, self.database)
      return data
```

I've tried to do the following the mock the whole methods, but running coverage test shows that the code is not covered (due to the output is mocked)

```
import mock
import pytest

some_df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1]}

@pytest.fixture
def some_fixture(mocker):
   mocker.patch('Something.extract_data_from_db', return_value=some_df)

# Function to test
def test_extract_data_from_db(some_fixture):
   assert some_fixture.extract_data_from_db
```